# Interpreting F and p statistics from R grangertest results

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, granger-causality

I using Rs grangertest to do some granger causality testing.  I'm testing a particular time series against an economic index time series and adjusting the lag in hopes of identifying the "best" relationship. In statistical terms I'm trying to reject the null hypothesis that the lagged index improves the regression at various lags.   From my statistics course, very simplified, I remember that Big F and Small p rejects the null hypothesis.   My question is this, in the two examples below which results seems to have the "better relationship:

1. Lag = 2, F = 26.4 p = 1.513e -6
2. Lag = 4, F = 12.0 p = 8.521e -8

In the first case the F is bigger, but the p is smaller and the in the second case the F is smaller, but the p is bigger.

So put another way, when trying to determine the "best" relationship does F trump p or does p trump F.